# Not able to add data into database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I created a 8 column table in SQL Server 2008. I entered data into 1st 2 column of the table and remaining columns I left allow nulls.

I am trying to add data to remaining 6 columns based on the data entered in 1st 2 columns, but I'm not able to add the data. Was leaving another 6 columns into "Allow nulls" caused this problem.

If yes, is there any solution for this?

Thanks.

```
string str = (@"Data Source=.\;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");

try
{
    String sql = "(UPDATE usn SET firstname = @st1, lastname = @st2, password = @st3, address = @st4, bloodgrp = @st5, contactnum = @st6, email = @st7 WHERE usn = '" + omd + "' )";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st1", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st2", TextBox2.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st3", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st4", TextBox10.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st5", TextBox6.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st6", TextBox7.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@st7", TextBox8.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("accountcreated.aspx");

        conn.Close();
    }
```

The first 2 columns of the data base includes regnum and name of the customer associated with regnum. The rest of the fields i am using to created account for those customer. So the regnum of specified users are already stored in 1st two columns. Based on this method i need to add data to remaining 6 fields.

Comment: Before connection close why  you are redirecting to another page.

Comment: Do you get any error, and if so: what errors? Also: `UPDATE` is for updating **existing** data, while your title seems to indicate you want to **add new** data to the database (that would be the `INSERT` statement)

Comment: `WHERE usn = '" + omd + "'` should be updating the row where usn = the value in the `omd` variable... what is that? You said you the first two columns make your primary key - so that's what you should be using for an update statement.

Comment: Sir, even if I redirect the page after closing the connection, its not getting saved into database.

Comment: why you have used `()` in your query? also why not using parameterised query for `usn` parameter?

Comment: I din't got any error. When i created the table of 8 columns, I manually inserted data into the first 2 column and those data are the Regnum and names and rest 6 rows i left them as null preassuming that i can enter data based on the first to column. Now i want the user to enter the regnum assigned to him whn he does that he wil be asked to put the details such as firstname, lastname, password, address, bloodgrp, contactnum and email.